# How to replace a string and conserve capitalisation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, gsub

With Ruby, is it possible to replace a string and conserve capitalisation.

Idea is to match "good day" and turn it into "holler" and preserve the original capitalisation. Example:

Before:

```
Good day to you sir and lady.
Hello and good day.
```

After:

```
Holler to you sir and lady.
Hello and holler.
```

Comment: Just updated the question to show that I need to fully replace, not append.

Comment: updated my answer to match your new question

Comment: @AnApprentice - By preserving you meant for string like: `Hi, Good day to you sir and lady.` your desired change should be: `Hi, Holler to you sir and lady.`??

Comment: please check my updated answer i hope it will be help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are planning to keep part of the string and append to it, use back reference and case-insensitive search pattern

```
yourstring.gsub(/(good day)/i, "\\1 and good night")
```

You can find explanation on how regular expressions work in `ruby` in [rubular](http://rubular.com/)

**Update**

Since, as you state in your comment and your updated question, you want the first letter of the replacement capitalized or not, according to pattern, I think this slightly verbose yet efficient `gsub` approach can help you:

```
string = "Good day to you sir and lady. \nHello and good day."
puts string.gsub(/[gG]ood day/, 'good day' =>'holler', 'Good day'=>'Holler')
# Holler to you sir and lady.
# Hello and holler.
```

As per `ruby 1.8.7`, `gsub` can accept a hash as a second parameter with alternative replacements of the possible matches the pattern describes. Thus, the above syntax is equivalent to:

```
puts string.gsub(/[gG]ood day/, {'good day' =>'holler', 'Good day'=>'Holler'})
```

Comment: that was just an example, I'm looking to completely replace not append at all.

Comment: So, you want the first letter of the sentence to be capital? Or if the first letter of the pattern is capital, the first letter of the replacement should be capital?

Comment: First letter of the pattern not the first letter of the sentence

Answer (score 1):

you can use the Regexp escape method with the ignore case option to do such a thing:

`reg = Regexp.new(Regexp.escape("good day"), Regexp::IGNORECASE)`

```
"good day".gsub(reg){|match| "#{match} and good night" }
=> "good day and good night"


"Good dAy".gsub(reg){|match| "#{match} and good night" }
=> "Good dAy and good night"
```

**EDIT to match the updated question**

using a similar idea to the answer for the original question

```
"Good day".gsub(reg){|match| "#{match.capitalize == match ? 'Holler' : 'holler'} and good night" }
=> "Holler and good night"

"good day".gsub(reg){|match| "#{match.capitalize == match ? 'Holler' : 'holler'} and good night" }
=> "holler and good night"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a block to `gsub` and you can manipulate the matched string

And the option **`i`** passed will make the regex case insensitive

```
string = "Good day to you sir and lady."

string.gsub(/good day/i) { |m| "#{m} and good night" }

#=> "Good day and good night to you sir and lady."

string = "Hello and good day."

string.gsub(/good day/i) { |m| "#{m} and good night" }

#=> "Hello and good day and good night."
```

Refer [**`gsub`**](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-gsub)

Answer (score 1):

This method :

- Applies a case-insensitive search for `old_str` in `text`
- For every `old_str` found :

  - it iterates `new_str` and `old_str` characters in parallel
  - it applies the `old_str` case on `new_str`

---

```
def case_aware_replace(text, old_str, new_str)
  text.gsub(/#{old_str}/i) do |word|
    new_str.chars.zip(word.chars).map do |new_char, old_char|
      if old_char
        old_char.downcase == old_char ? new_char : new_char.upcase
      else
        new_char
      end
    end.join
  end
end

puts case_aware_replace('Good day to you sir and lady.', 'good day', 'holler')
#=> Holler to you sir and lady.

puts case_aware_replace('Hello and good day.', 'good day', 'holler')
#=> Hello and holler.

puts case_aware_replace('HELLO GRANDMA!', 'hello', 'hi')
#=> HI GRANDMA!

puts case_aware_replace('AaAaAaA', 'a', 'b')
#=> BbBbBbB

puts case_aware_replace('AaAaAaA', 'a', 'b ')
#=> B b B b B b B

puts case_aware_replace(case_aware_replace(case_aware_replace('IBM', 'i', 'international '),'b', 'business '),'m', 'machines ')
#=> International Business Machines
```

Answer (score -1):

sure there will be more elegant solutions, but this can also help.

```
2.3.1 :003 > a = "Good day to you sir and lady".downcase.gsub('good day', 'good day and good night').capitalize
 => "Good day and good night to you sir and lady"
```

what i've done is,

- changed all letters to downcase,
- substituted the relevant parts,
- then capitalized.

Comment: This will not work for the second line in his question, he doesnt want to capitalize everytime, he wants to protect the original capitalisation, meaning if the `good day` in the string is not capitalized, it should not be capitalized in the result, as stated in the second line of his example

Answer (score -1):

```
a = 'Good day to you sir and lady.
Hello and good day.'

a.gsub!('Good day', 'Hellor').gsub!('good day', 'hellor')
```

would return

```
Hellor to you sir and lady.                                                                                                                                                                             
Hello and hellor.
```

There are only two cases (assuming only initials can be capitalised), replacing two cases directly should be sufficient.